Oracle Apex - Rest data source parameters
I'm using oracle apex version 23.2.
I have a rest data source of type = Simple HTTP that i'm trying to filter by a query parameter named "fieldvalue".
When I input my entire url into the url path prefix like so api/v2/search.json?query=type:ticket fieldvalue:12345678 and test the operation, it appropriately returns the result set i'm looking for.
When I remove fieldvalue:12345678 from the url prefix and try to turn it into a parameter, I can never get the correct results. I've tried using it as a url pattern, url query string, http header, and a request body.
The way the query string documentation reads, I should be able to create two variables and append them to my path. So I shortened my path to just api/v2/search.json. I created two variables, both of type query string. One of which is static with name = query and default value = type:ticket. The other is name = fieldvalue and the default value = 12345678 with the data type set to numeric and required set to on. When I test this operation it just returns all of the tickets and ignores my parameters completely.
The documentation makes it seem so simple and straight forward. Does anyone know what i'm missing here?

How have you defined the REST API parameter? Please share your code handler SQL or PLSQ code block as well.

@thatjeffsmith I'm not sure what you mean. There is no sql or plsql code block in the rest data source parameters. I added my rest data source type in the description above, but I don't think that's what you're asking for.

ah, you're using a 3rd party rest api, not an oracle/ords/apex rest api - be sure to include those details in your questions so we don't have to guess

For a REST Data Source, everything after the question mark is a Query String parameter, and in your case, this is one parameter named query with a value of type:ticket fieldvalue:12345678.
However, when you create the REST Source, the wizard will be a bit confused about the colons in your parameter value - it thinks that these indicate additional parameters. So you might create the REST Source a bit different ...

On the first wizard step, only provide the URL until the question mark, i.e.  api/v2/search.json.
Advance to the Advanced wizard step
then configure one parameter

Type Query String
Name query
Value type:ticket fieldvalue:12345678






Much appreciated! Does that mean there will always only be one parameter when using the parameter type "URL Query String"? How would I know when to separate them into separate params and when to concatenate?

No, you can have multiple Query String parameters. However, the query string is defined as: ?param-name1=value1&param-name=value2....&param-nameN=valueN.
However, your very REST API defines only one(!) query string parameter named query. The value is -again- some syntax - but very specific to your REST API - not to the HTTP standard. So, for the REST Data Source there is only one parameter, as your REST API only defines one. Your application needs to  build the actual query parameter value as the REST API expects it ...

The Oracle ORDS filter grammar follows a similar semantics: the query string parameter is named just q - and it's value can be a complex JSON, expressing SQL filters: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2022/02/filtering-and-searching-strings-using-ords-query-parameters/
For ORDS, we have built-in support in APEX - as APEX does not know about your REST API, there is no such support. It would be possible to author a REST Source Plug-In which is able to understand the syntax of your REST API, but that is quite some effort ...
